# How to determine whether a string is a subsequence of another string regardless of characters in between?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to write a code that will tell me if one string is a substring of another string. The catch is that it does not matter if there are characters in between and the only characters that matter are `'A'`, `'T'`, `'G'` and `'C'`. For instance:

```
"TxxAA" is     a subsequence of "CTyyGCACA"
"pln"   is     a subsequence of "oiu"
"TAA"   is NOT a subsequence of "TCCCA"
```

Currently I am doing

```
private boolean subSequence(DNASequence other) {

    other.fix();
    boolean valid = false;
    String t = other.toString();
    data = dataFix(data);
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < t.length(); j++) {
            if(data.charAt(i) == t.charAt(j)) {                        
                if( j >= index) {
                    valid = true;
                    index = j;
                    t = t.replace(t.charAt(j), '_');
                } else {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    if (data == "" || t == "" ) {
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
}

private String dataFix(String data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i += 1) {
        char ch = data.charAt(i);
        if (("ATGC".indexOf(ch) < 0))
            data = data.replace(data.charAt(i), ' ');        
    }
    data = data.replaceAll(" ", "").trim();
    return data;
}
```

the `fix()` and `dataFix()` methods erase all characters besides `"ATGC"`. As the code iterates through, it is replacing the character in `t` that matches with `data.charAt(i)` with a `_` so that it does not rematch the same letter (I was having that problem).

Currently, what is happening is that the replace function is replacing every char in the string not just the char at the specific index (which is what it is supposed to do) What is a better way to approach this problem? Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Your `dataFix` can remove all non-DNA letters by doing `data.replaceAll("[^ATGC]", "")` -- in fact the whole method could be `private String dataFix(final String data) { return data.replaceAll("[^ATGC]", ""); }` because replacing non-ATGC chars with nothing _includes_ replacing spaces with nothing (removing them) which also gets leading and trailing spaces, so you don't need the additional `.trim()` (you don't need the trim() in your dataFix as you have it now, for the same reason: `replaceAll(" ", "")` will remove leading and trailing spaces already, not just internal spaces)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the first question 'What is a better way to approach this problem?', I would recommend using Regular Expressions (or regex).  Regular Expressions are a way to express patterns in text.

For this example where you have a search term:

```
TxxAA
```

a regex to describe the patter you are looking for could be:

```
T.*A.*A
```

Without going into too much detail the term .* is an expression for any number (zero or more) of any characters.  So this regex describes a pattern which is: T; then any characters; A; then any characters; and then A.

Your original question becomes "does a sequence have a sub-sequence with the pattern T.*A.*A?".  Java has a regex library built in and you can use the Pattern and Matcher objects to answer this question.

Some sample code as a demonstration:

```
public class DnaMatcher {

    static boolean isSearchChar(char c) {
        return 'A' == c || 'T' == c || 'G' == c || 'C' == c;
    }

    static Pattern preparePattern(String searchSequence) {
        StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = false;
        for (char c : searchSequence.toCharArray()) {
            if (isSearchChar(c)) {
                if (first) {
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    pattern.append(".*");
                }
                pattern.append(c);
            }
        }
        return Pattern.compile(pattern.toString());
    }

    static boolean contains(String sequence, String searchSequence) {
        Pattern pattern = preparePattern(searchSequence);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sequence);
        return matcher.find();
    }

    public static void main(String...none) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(contains("CTyyGCACA", "TxxAA")); // true
        System.out.println(contains("TCCCA", "TAA")); // false
    }
}
```

You can see that the preparePattern matches prepares the regex expression as discussed.

Answer (score 4):

Understanding that the strings might be very long, a regular expression check might take some time.

```
static String fix(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("[^ACGT]+", "");
}

static boolean isSubSequence(String sought, String chain) {
    sought = fix(sought);
    chain = fix(chain);
    char[] soughtChars = sought.toCharArray();
    char[] chainChars = chain.toCharArray();
    int si = 0;
    for (int ci = 0; si < soughtChars.length && ci < chainChars.length; ++ci) {
        if (chainChars[ci] == soughtChars[si]) {
            ++si;
        }
    }
    return si >= soughtChars.length;
}
```

Or

```
static boolean isSubSequence(String sought, String chain) {
    sought = fix(sought);
    chain = fix(chain);
    int ci = 0;
    for (char ch : sought.toCharArray()) {
        ci = chain.indexOf(ch, ci);
        if (ci < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        ++ci;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem seems more the sense of such a result.

---

***Comparing with regex:***

I did a comparison:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10_000);
    Random random = new Random(42);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10_1000 - 6; ++i) {
        sb.append("ACGT".charAt(random.nextInt(3)));
    }
    sb.append("TTAGTA");
    String s = sb.toString();
    String t = "TAGAAG";
    {
        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        boolean found = contains(s, t);
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("Found: %s in %d ms%n", found, (t1 - t0) / 1000_000L);
    }
    {
        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        boolean found = isSubSequence(t, s);
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("Found: %s in %d ms%n", found, (t1 - t0) / 1000_000L);
    }
```

Results

```
Found: false in 31829 ms --> Regex
Found: false in 5 ms     --> indexOf
```

But: the case is quite artificial: failure on a short string.

Comment: Looks like this approach achieves best possible:  `O(M+N)`

Comment: @javadba yes  and trivial code actually. I think there is some inkling to have a more complex solution for "gene" processing.

Comment: Just noticed one thing - which does not affect asymptotic but does on constant factor. Why not use *2* pointers instead of the chain.indexOf. Keep a running pointer on the `chain` - since once a character were seen it need not be evaluated again. come to think of it - the asymptotic efficiency *is* affected: using `indexOf` would give `O(M*N)`

Comment: `ci = chain.indexOf(ch, ci)` searches the `ch` from the current position `ci`. If found, ci is increased after the found characters. And the for loop picks the next sought char. This should be sufficiently optimal. C++ pointers would indeed place the pointer ahead if that is what you mean.

Comment: The complexity of a simple regular expression match is O(N).

Comment: @EvanJones Searching ACT in AGAC would indeed do A--C but on _failed_ match might try --AC? Or is the regex internal grammar clever/ideal? I would think on non-matching strings much backtracking is done. But I might be mistaken.

Comment: Hi @JoopEggen, regex implementations are pretty smart.  I did a test on 200 x 20,000 length strings (randomly generated with letters 'A-Z') and 200 x 2,000 length search terms. Ran them all against each other (40,000 trials) and on my PC the regex approach had better performance.

Comment: @EvanJones that is awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @EvanJones I still found a "bad case" example. See my answer.

Comment: Hi @JoopEggen, yes, I am seeing the same.  For my experiment with the random strings you would expect every test to match.  When I forced a failed match for each test your implementation was faster.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a (relatively) simple recursion:

```
 /**
 * Returns true is s1 is a subsequence of s2, false otherwise
 */
private static boolean isSubSeq(String s1, String s2) {
    if ("".equals(s1)) {
        return true;
    }
    String first = s1.substring(0, 1);
    s1 = s1.substring(1);
    int index = s2.indexOf(first);
    if (index == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    s2 = s2.substring(index+1);
    return isSubSeq(s1, s2);

}
```

*Algorithm*: look for the first index of the first character of s1 in s2, if there is no such index - the answer is false, if there is, we can continue looking (recursively) for the next letter starting at position index+1

**EDIT**
It seems that you need to sanitize your input to include only the characters: 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C'

It's easy to do (following runs on Java 9, but it's easy to modify to lower versions of Java):

```
private static String sanitize(String s) {
    String result = "";
    List<Character> valid = List.of( 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C');
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (valid.contains(c)) {
            result += c;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then it's used as follows (example):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "TxxAA";
        String s2 = "CTyyGCACA";
        s1 = sanitize(s1); // you need to sanitize only s1, can you see why?
        System.out.println(isSubSeq(s1, s2));
    }
```

Comment: I am still getting errors, for example. "GxAyAzCw" should be a subsequence of "TTCGCATCTATCT".
expected:<true> but was:<false>

Comment: "abc" should be a subsequence of "xyzw". expected:<true>
but was:<false> This is another error I am getting.

Comment: @alfasin of course you're right about what a subsequence really is, but... Since only `ATGC` count, and everything else is effectively removed, then `"abc"` becomes `""` and `"xyzw"` becomes `""` ... and `""` is indeed a "subsequence" of `""`

Comment: Oh I see. In that case the OP can sanitize the input and remove all the irrelevant characters as 'preprocessing' stage, before calling the method that checks if one string is a subsequence of another.

Comment: @Siddharth bhatt it's not relevant here

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on the question, the string can be sanitized with a regular expression that will eliminate all characters that are not ATGC (including spaces and trim() that OP is doing) in a simple method `private String dataFix(final String data) { return data.replaceAll("[^ATGC]", ""); }`